# img.on("load") firing far too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is executing almost 100 times for the 10 images it's supposed to handle the src-loaded event for. Not exactly what I expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
//next line contains a stringof <img> tags wrapped in divs
$(".carousel-inner").append(htmlStreamImage);
//this next clause is the problem-child
$(".carousel-inner div.item img").on("load", function () {
    //build the indicators list
    foo();

    console.debug(accumulator++);
    if (carouselImagesLoaded == numberPhotos) {
       foo2();
    }
}).each(function () {
    if (this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Comment: Where and when do you set the `src` for each element?

Comment: Literally right above it. I've included it in an edit. In case this is important, this is in the success clause of .ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You can downsize your code:

```
$(".carousel-inner").append(
    $("<img/>").attr({...}).load(function(){
        // building process
    })
);
```